# How to get the report to email by using windows task scheduler

Tags: windows, csv, outlook

i wrote a program like ,writing the data from db into a csv file and that csv file will be emailed to my official email after the script runs successfully. i am able to get the report when running the file manually. but not able to get email when running the file by windows scheduler. Can anyone help me what might be the reason.

```
import smtplib
import sqlite3;
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
g_db=Sqlite3.connect('yyy.db');
cur=g_db.cursor
res=open('yyy.csv','w')
cur.execute('select * from table')
for r in cur:
   res.write(r[0]);
   res.write("\n");
res.close()     
fp=open('yyy.csv',"rb")
to='yyy@xxx.com'
msg=MIMEText(fp.read())
fp.close()
msg['From']="yyyy"
msg['To']=to
msg['Cc']=cc
s = smtplib.SMTP('xxx.xxx.com',25)
s.sendmail('xxx.com',[to,cc],msg.as_string())
```

And the settings for task schedular is:
1.run when user is only login
2.run with highest priliviges
3.set the time under triggers tab
4.Under actions tab i selected 'start a program' and i provided the script path which needs to be run.
it is triggering the event by the time which i set and last run result is showing as 0x1.
when i am running manually,it is sending the report to my email,but i am not getting email report when task is run through Task scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

You can post the script that you are using to do that, and the settings for the Windows Scheduler to execute this script.

Anyhow, a thing might be the fact that when you execute your script manually it is executed as the user that you are currently logged in with. When Windows Scheduler executes it, most likely, the user is different, therefore you might encounter privilege related or settings related errors.

Would be nice to have more details about what exactly you are doing.

Comment: added my code and windows settings.please let me know what might be the wrong.